# SAVING EXCEL DATA TO PHPMYADMIN USING PHP

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I already have this code that can read data from excel, but the problem is saving it to the database with the use of PHPMyAdmin, I can save the data to the database but the problem is, I can only save the first row not the whole data from excel.

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');
include('Classes/PHPExcel.php');

$tmpfname = "uploads/test2.xlsx";

$excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($tmpfname);
$excelObj = $excelReader->load($tmpfname);
$worksheet = $excelObj->getActiveSheet();
$lastRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow();
//$lastCol = $worksheet->getHighestCol();

$aaa = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

echo "<table border='ridge' id='results'>";
for($row = 1; $row <= $lastRow; $row++){
    echo '<tr>';    
    for($i=0; $i < 26; $i++)    
    {
        $value = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getFormattedValue();
        $color = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB();
        $border = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle();
        $fontstyle1 = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getBold();
        $fontstyle2 = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getItalic();
        $fontstyle3 = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getUnderline();
        $fontsize = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getSize();
        $fontname = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getName();
        $alignment = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getAlignment()->getHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
        $fontcolor = $worksheet->getCell($aaa[$i].$row)->getStyle($aaa[$i].$row)->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB();
        $fontcolorall = $fontstyle1.$fontstyle2.$fontstyle3;

        $hello = mysqli_query($conn, "insert into tags_xml(value, color, border, fontstyle, fontsize, fontname, alignment, fontcolor)
            values('$value','$color','$border','$fontcolorall','$fontsize','$fontname','$alignment','$fontcolor');");   

        echo '<td><span id="value">'. $value.' </span>|
            <span id="color">'.$color.'</span> | 
            <span id="border">'.$border.' </span> | 
            <span id="fontstyle">'.$fontstyle1.'
            '.$fontstyle2.'
            '.$fontstyle3.'</span> | 
            <span id="fontsize">'.$fontsize.' </span> |
            <span id="fontname">'.$fontname.' </span> |
            <span id="alignment">'.$alignment.' </span> |
            <span id="fontcolor">'.$fontcolor.'</span> |
            </td>'; 
    }
    echo '</tr>';   
}
echo "</table>";

/* $background_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFill()->getStartColor()->getRGB(); 
$fore_color = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getColor()->getRGB(); 
$font_bold = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getBold(); 
$font_italic = $cell->getStyle()->getFont()->getItalic(); 
$bordo = $cell->getStyle()->getBorders()->getTop()->getBorderStyle(); */
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: `mysqli_query()` is unclear. Please brief about it.

Comment: i fount out it already, thank you! hehehe sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an administrative tool for managing databases. You can directly import a CSV file through phpMyAdmin (which you could export from Excel), but phpMyAdmin is just an interface to MySQL or MariaDB.